# git: command not found (on OS X 10.5)

Tags: git, macos

I am receiving this error when I try to use git lately.  I'm not exactly sure when the error started as I rarely use git.
I used to use it.  I didn't change anything about it or my machine that I know of.  Now it doesn't work.

I've gone through and reinstalled the latest version using [this](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) installer, and I still get the same error in terminal.

Anyone heard of this before?  The installer runs just fine, no errors, but it still doesn't recognize the "git" command in terminal.

I'm running OS 10.5

**EDIT**

Per a response down below which pointed me to my PATH variable I think that's the issue.
I installed MacPorts at one point, which changed my .profile
I have no idea how to change it back though.
My old .profile was this:

```
alias g='git'
export PS1='$(git branch &>/dev/null; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then \
echo "\[\033[00m\]$(git branch grep ^*sed s/\*\ //) "; fi)\$\[\033[00m\] '
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

My new .profile is this:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

How can I make those two files become one?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the page you linked to:

```
/usr/local/git/bin
```

Is that in your PATH?

Open `~/.profile` in your favorite editor and add the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
```

This appends the item to your PATH variable (separarated by colons), so it's compatible with other commands that modify the path.

Comment: Ah!, well that's something...but I don't know what to do.  Please check the edited question.

Comment: Do I need to logout/login to make these changes visible or should it just "work"?

Comment: OS X sources your profile every time you open a terminal, I think.

Comment: this worked for me in 10.6.4 as well. I had just installed MacPorts

Comment: 10.5 Server, open directory (LDAPv3/127.0.0.1) user [username]. Home directory is set to afp://localhost/Users/[username] (from Workgroup Manager). on a remote SSH from my work computer, "cd ~" then "pwd" confirm that the home directory of [username] is indeed /Users/[username]. Echoing $PATH from said SSH connection shows only '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', although the .bash_profile file I created at the home directory clearly adds '/usr/local/git/bin'. Remote Git commands via SSH from work computer return 'command not found'. What am I missing?

Comment: <rant>I just want to write code; why do I have to be a server admin? When will the dark ages of the command line be finally over? </rant>

Comment: My git is installed at /usr/local/bin/git instead of the given /usr/local/git/bin

Answer (score 26):

Had the same issue on mountain lion.

If yo're using XCode, run it.
then go to XCode->preferences and install "Command Line Tools".

thats it,
worked for me.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mountain-lion-git-fix/

Comment: Thanks, this was the fast and easy way to fix it!

Comment: Also consider @lorddev's answer: with Xcode, set up bash profile `alias git='xcrun git'`

Answer (score 11):

Another way to approach this is to check to see if you have an `/etc/paths.d/git` file. The OSX installer should have created that file containing:

`/usr/local/git/bin`

so that it is picked up without any .bash_profile needed, or at least no special entries in your .bash_profile, or .profile in your case.

I just tested deleting my .bash_profile and opening a fresh shell window and I'm still able to resolve the `git` command.

Comment: Perfect! Updating the ~/.profile file did not work for my setup.

Comment: I didn't have any .bash_profile to begin with, so I fail to see how deleting it would fix this.

Comment: Under 10.8, this seems to be the /etc/paths file. Just edit it with
    sudo nano /etc/paths

Comment: Yeah, both /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d/git will work. The path_helper utility will blend the contents of /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d/* and de-dupe them. I think the reason to pick /etc/paths.d/* is just to have a reminder of what process needed that path, if it isn't readily apparent. Otherwise, I don't think it matters which is used. See `man path_helper` for more info. Also, this whole question should now be answered with "install and run homebrew to keep git up to date." :)

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was

1. Installing the latest version of Xcode from the App Store
2. Running `alias git='xcrun git'` per [this guy](https://ja.twitter.com/UIResponder/status/183976704140779521).

Answer (score 5):

In case people still get this problem, make sure the /usr/libexec/path_helper is executable. I had this problem when I installed Prezto.

```
sudo chmod ugo+x /usr/libexec/path_helper
```

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to your home directory:

```
cd ~
```

You can verify you are in the correct directory by printing your working directory:

```
pwd
```

It should output something like:  **/user/YOUR_USER**

Then open up your bash profile:

```
vi .bash_profile
```

You should see something like the following:

[image: Bash Profile VI]

Then press 'i' to enter insert mode

[image: insert mode]

Then add your export to the file(You can use <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to copy paste):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Then press the 'esc' button -> then type in the following to write your changes and quit:

```
:wq
```

Then press enter.

Next, you will need to close and quit the terminal and then open a new one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was nothing wrong with my `path`, but whether XCode is correctly installed or not.

In the Terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal), type and **run**:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This command will download and install XCode Developer Tools and you won't see that message again.

Or, depending on where you problem lies, running the following command may also help:

```
xcode-select --reset
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since this was the top result in my Google search for: "git-clone: command not found" , I would add in my case I only needed to remove the dash, i.e.
"git clone" instead of "git-clone" and that resolved my issue, I was following a tutorial where dash appeared to be used