# how do I add /usr/local/git/bin/ to the PATH on mac osx?

Tags: git, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835837/git-command-not-found)

how do I add /usr/local/git/bin/ to the PATH on mac osx? I just installed git but it is not recognizing commands. It only responds with "command git not found", and I believe this may be the solution but I do not know how to add it to the path to be used in terminal.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can add the following to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

The change will get applied with the next terminal window you open.

Comment: Thank you. How do i add that to the ~/.bash_profile? does it already exist? or is it a file I have to create?

Comment: You can create it if it doesn't exist, but it should be there already. Open up Terminal (Applications/Utilities), and type `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit ~/.bash_profile`. The file is hidden (because it starts with a .), which is why you can't open it using the File/Open menu by default.

Comment: ~\.bash_profile can easily not exist.  If it does not exist you should create it as a normal text file.  And fyi, on OSX ~\ means the users home folder.

Comment: you can also run this directly in command-line `export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH`

Comment: You can also just run `source ~/.bash_profile` so you don't have to restart your terminal window.

Comment: add `"git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git"` in `settings.json`