# adding ~/bin directory in your path

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I need to add ~/bin directory in your path.

But I am not sure what the actual command for this is, I know it goes in my .bash_profile

Does anyone know this, or a tutorial on how to set up a new .bash_profile for a terminal on a new mac (UNIX)

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545715/how-do-i-add-usr-local-git-bin-to-the-path-on-mac-osx
Else vim ~/.bash_profile will create a bash profile and then type into it export PATH=$PATH:<additional-path>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to .bash_profile:

`export PATH="$PATH":~/bin`

If you don't have a .bash_profile, just create it.