# GIT and 'mountain lion' and ' export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH '

Tags: git, bash, osx-mountain-lion, dyld

I have installed GIT on my Mac mountain lion 10.8.5
I cannot get the GIT commands to execute.

original issue:
terminal

```
git init new_repository

dyld:lazy symbol binding failed: symbol not found
```

I found several posts relating to the $PATH and I am close to understanding the concepts of these paths but I am uncertain as to where I should be, which directory  ?? I should run the following command.
    git init new_repository

This was suggested in post and had 53 up votes.

[how do I add /usr/local/git/bin/ to the PATH on mac osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545715/how-do-i-add-usr-local-git-bin-to-the-path-on-mac-osx/5545748#5545748)

Begin of that posted answer
You can add the following to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

The change will get applied with the next terminal window you open.
End of answer.

Editing my .bash_profile with the above code did not change anything.

Below is my current path.  Maybe someone will notice something that I am missing.

```
~ mycomputer $ echo $PATH
~ mycomputer $ pwd
/Users/mycomputer
~ mycomputer $ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
mycomputer:~ mycomputer$
```

I want to be able to run git from terminal.
Can someone explain Things ?
Which file do I modify to include What PATH ?

thanks

Comment: consider editting your question to show the output of running `echo ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-LD_LIB_PATH_NOT_SET}` (there are only 2 "words" in that command). Good luck.

Comment: Try only git init command once.

Comment: `which` finds commands in the `$PATH` your `.bash_profile` file is not one of those.

Comment: Have you tried in a new terminal instance?

Comment: @Etan Reisner new instance didn't do it.

Comment: The command @shellter indicated will print out the value of that variable. The reason your edits don't work is because code needs non-text line directly above it.

Comment: What does `otool -L "$(type -p git)"` say?

Comment: @Etan Reisner sorry. i replied 4 minutes after you suggested that but dont know why it didn't show up here. 'command not found'

Comment: Hm... was that complaining about `otool` not being found? That's unfortunate.

Comment: @EtanReisner: `$HOME/.bash_profile` is sourced by bash on startup; it doesn't need to be in `$PATH`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I know. I was explaining why `which` didn't find it when the OP tried it (in a bit of the post that has since been removed).

Comment: @keiththompson it has been suggested that I uninstall GIT and reinstall a different version.it sounds like you are very familiar with my issue. What code should I insert into the bash_profile so that GIT can locate the library it needs to run ? I think that is the problem ? Two days of trouble shooting and reading and I cannot find a clear resolution. I would still like to get the version I have running rather than an uninstall reinstall. I am on mountain lion 10.8.5. GIT version 2.0.1 Thanks

Comment: @shareyourpeace: I don't know. I don't use MacOS. On Linux, installing git puts everything in the default locations, so I don't need to mess with `$PATH` or `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @keithThompson. Thanks. I know some Linux/unix but this project is Mac oriented.