# R animation error: how to install ImageMagick?

Tags: r, animation, installation, imagemagick

I intend to run some R Animation demo code but this error message returns

```
Warning messages:
1: In im.convert(img.files, output = movie.name, convert = convert,  :
  Please install ImageMagick first or put its bin path into the system PATH variable
```

I've downloaded ImageMagic for mac. It's a folder with subfolders like `bin`, `lib`, `share` etc. How can put its `bin` path into system path? Thanks.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5545715/903061

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

Put something like

```
PATH=$PATH:blablabla/ImageMagic/bin
```

in `~/.bashrc` file.

- `$PATH` is the original `PATH` variable;
- `:` is used to separate different candidates;
- the final `blablabla/ImageMagic/bin` denotes the path to the executable.

Whenever you open up a new terminal, `~/.bashrc` file will be run, hence environmental variable `PATH` will be set as above. If you start up your R from terminal, this should do the work.

**Option 2:**

If you normally invoke R by clicking its icon, then `~/.bashrc` may not work. In this case, use the `~/.profile` file instead. This is run whenever you log in. Add the following to the bottom of this file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:blablabla/ImageMagic/bin
```

(Note `export` here. You may need to log out and log in again so that the setting takes effect.)

---

**Comments**

- Both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` are hidden files. You may use `ls -a ~` to see them. To edit/save them, use the normal text editor.
- The link @Gregor gives, suggests using `~/.bash_profile`. Well, These days this file is normally replaced by `~/.profile`. But you should use `ls -a ~` to check.

**follow up:**

OK, so you have `.bash_profile` instead of `.profile` on your machine.

To open this file, do:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then move to the bottom, and add the line you need:

```
export PATH=$PATH:blablabla/ImageMagic/bin
```

To save edit, do `ctrl + O` (maybe hitting an `ENTER` as well); then you quit editor by `ctrl + X`.

If you do not want to log out and log in again to let new setting take effect, try:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: thank you for answering. I normally click its icon, so option 2. in terminal when I run ls -a ~ I could see  .bash_history
.bash_profile
.bash_profile.pysave
.bash_sessions what should I do next and how can I open bash-profile?

Comment: I'm quite useless in terminal. I tried this and it doesn't open the bash file: subl ~/.bash_profile

Comment: thanks, that does work, but i notice that export line seems to be for python though. These are the last few lines after sudo nano:
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5 # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Comment: after adding the line i tried both ctrl+o and ctrl+x to save it, but it doesn't seem to get saved and nothing happens

Comment: right, it stayed in the same page instead of exit nano editor after ctrl+x

Comment: ur advice is awesome! so that line added, I pointed the path to download as ImageMagick is there now export PATH=$PATH:Downloads/ImageMagic/bin 
but still same error msg in R after trying both source ~/.bash_profile and log out log in

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Windows a few weeks ago. I don't know if it is the same on Mac or not, but it is worth a try.

When you go to download ImageMagick there should be a prompt that says something like "select additional tasks." Be sure to check "Install Legacy Utilities (e.g. convert)." I think they changed the names of a few things between versions. That selection names things properly for R. Also, if this happens to be the same issue I had (maybe, maybe not) be sure to restart R before trying again after you've downloaded it.

Comment: thank you very much, it doesn't ask me to select additional tasks though