# selenium can't find chromedriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to make a simple application with webdrivers and selenium could not find chromedriver when i open the app.js, Here is my code:

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

driver.get('http://www.helisos.win')
```

and here is the console error

```
Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
at new ServiceBuilder (C:\Users\pcrunn\Desktop\GermBot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:232:13)
at getDefaultService (C:\Users\pcrunn\Desktop\GermBot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:321:22)
at Function.createSession (C:\Users\pcrunn\Desktop\GermBot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:696:44)
at createDriver (C:\Users\pcrunn\Desktop\GermBot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:155:33)
at Builder.build (C:\Users\pcrunn\Desktop\GermBot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:647:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pcrunn\Desktop\GermBot\app.js:3:88)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

Its my first post on stackoverflow. Sorry If you have any issues with understanding what is my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the driver [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home), and then add to the system path variable:

### Windows

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272417/7970301

### Linux

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059

### Macos

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5545748/7970301

Comment: I forgot to mention. I have it already and it works on cmd by typing "chromedriver", I think the issue is on adding it on system variable I added but it still not work.