# Linux console: git command not found on x64 Cent OS

Tags: linux, git, github

I have a completely fresh install of 64 Bit Cent OS 5.7, this is in VirtualBox on top of 64-bit XP.

I'm trying to install SSU.

**Problem: The command 'git' was not found. See "code" below please.**

Have tried looking this up: */usr/local/git/* does not exist: [git: command not found (on OS X 10.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835837/git-command-not-found)

I don't care about source code: I just want git to work so SSU will install so I can try to access the bank on what seems like a huge whim.

I am signed in to Gnome as root and seem to be able to access my computer normally without being harassed about passwords excessively and can create or edit files.

```
[root@localhost ~]# $ git clone https://github.com/wesabe/ssu
bash: $: command not found
```

**Concerns**

Unfortunately every single time I ask these kinds of questions and don't make clarifications I end up having to make those clarifications. So...

No negativity or rudeness intended what-so-ever: if the answer involves editing a text file or copy-and-paste actions please tell me the locations to do so in the file manager instead of console commands. I'm perfectly okay copying and pasting console commands for things that really should be done in the console though.

Note: there appear to be numerous "git" commands and numerous "ssu" commands. I do NOT know the difference between them and would really prefer someone who has solid expertise to answer so that I nor others end up accidentally trashing our copies of Linux as it's been very difficult to get anything to work and stay working thus extending my personal stay with XP.

I will be more than happy to  both accept an answer and thumbs it up should it be helpful.

Comment: "yum install git" was not able to find package.

Comment: write your command without the $

Answer (score 5):

I would first try installing `git`.  As root:

```
yum install git
```

Comment: Did not work, you added the answer about the same time I added the comment, thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](http://book.git-scm.com/2_installing_git.html),

```
yum install git-core
```

If that doesn't work you could add the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) source.  [There are also RPMs for git](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/RPMS/).

Comment: "No package git-core available." The RPM folders are all entirely empty for all processor types. I have no clue what I would do with EPEL.