# Get a "git command not found" error on mac though .profile file is updated

Tags: macos, git, terminal, .profile

I have read this thread when I got the  the
[git: command not found (on OS X 10.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835837/git-command-not-found)
error

which basically said to update ~/.profile file with this phrase:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I did that and it didn't work. but if I just write this code in the terminal the "git" command did work - but only until I have closed the terminal - then I need to retype this code whenever I want git to work.

My suspicious is that I have another ".profile" file somewhere in my mac and that the file I have updated is irrelevant (since it didn't work).

Is that the case and if so - how do I find this file?

Comment: Did you relaunch a new shell session, and did you typed `echo $PATH` to check the value of `$PATH` (and see if it contains `/usr/local/git/bin`)? Does `/usr/local/git/bin/git --version`works?

Comment: "/usr/local/git/bin/git --version" works - but I don't see /usr/local/git/bin in "echo $PATH" - how do I know where this $PATH is defined so I will know where to change it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line to your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
source ~/.profile
```

This excellent super user answer explains why:
[Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/a/183980)