# Github not installed in terminal os

Tags: macos, github-for-mac

I downloaded and installed GitHub (latest version) for OS X, installed command line utility under **Github** in the application and am coming up with an error trying to create my first readme file in a repo entitled "basic-twitbstrap".

```
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro-2:basic-twitbstrap macbook$ git init
-bash: git: command not found
```

Comment: I believe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835837/git-command-not-found

Comment: Not the command and directory is git not github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the latest version of Ruby Version Manager, then entered 'git' into the Terminal. It came up with a list of usage and common commands.

Now it runs.

```
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro-2:~ macbook$ git --version
git version 1.7.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're not installed in standard location, command-line programs need some environment modifications to be called, which consists in adding their directory to the PATH environment variable.

So in your case you need to add `/usr/local/github` to your path, [see how](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/).

Comment: Macbooks-MacBook-Pro-2:basic-twitbstrap macbook$ /usr/local/github
    -bash: /usr/local/github: No such file or directory
    Macbooks-MacBook-Pro-2:basic-twitbstrap macbook$ usr/local/github git init
    -bash: usr/local/github: No such file or directory

Comment: @Max: please say what you tried instead of copy-paste your commands

Comment: I tried to access the github in the /usr/local/github. It resulted in the error of "no such file or directory".

Comment: I read how to alter the PATH to include git in the link above, however I cannot find the .profile in order to edit it. I tried to do "open .profile". It came up with the same error.